# Using gspread with oauth and have to re-authorize every time I re-run my code

Tags: oauth, gspread, python-3.10

- OS: Mint Linux 21.3
- Python: 3.10
- gspread: 6.0.0
- IDE: PyCHarm

I'm trying to use gspread to access a google spreadsheet and I've been able to successfully do so, however, I have to re-authorize every time I run the code.

I've set up the credentials properly

As shown below, I specify a location for the authorized user file, and when I run the code the first time, it creates the authorized user file and the code runs with the expected results.

However, when running the code again, the oath method does not appear to read that file, and I have to authorize again.  Once authorized again, the code runs as expected.

```
import gspread

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
SPREADSHEET_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

CRED_FILE = "client_secret.json"
AUTH_USER_FILE = 'auth_user.json'

gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename=CRED_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, authorized_user_filename=AUTH_USER_FILE)

# Open a sheet from a spreadsheet in one go
spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_ID)

ws = spreadsheet.get_worksheet(0)

# Update a range of cells using the top left corner address
ws.update([[1, 2], [3, 4]], 'A1')
```

Am I missing something?  Why does this require authorization every time it runs?  I assumed the authorization with work until it expires.

Notably, I've been playing with the google api client a bit, and when playing with that, once authorized, I don't have to authorize again.  The google api client is a bit over my head, so I wanted to switch over to using gspread.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, in the case of your script, when your script is run for the first time, the refresh token is put into `auth_user.json`. When the script is run again, the access token is retrieved using the refresh token from `auth_user.json`. From this situation, in your actual situation, how about confirming the following points? 1. When you run the script, is the file of `auth_user.json` created? 2. Does the file `auth_user.json` have the refresh token? 3. Can your script correctly read the file `auth_user.json`? If my comment was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, if I delete the auth_user.json file and run the script, the  auth_user.json file gets created.  If I run it again, it seems like it doesn't read the file again (or I'm not understanding how it works) and asks for authorization again.  There is a refresh_token in the auth_user.json, as well an "expiry" token, which looks to me like tomorrow sometime.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to `If I run it again, it seems like it doesn't read the file again`. But, I'm not sure about your actual situation. So, I cannot still provide a clear solution. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: FYI, found out that this is a bug in the gspread 6.0.0 library.  Downgrading to 5.12.4 resolves this issue.  Bug is reported and it is being addressed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, how about posting it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by downgrading to gspread 5.12.4, as noted in my prior reply.  The fix to qspread 6 is slated to be released in gspread 6.0.1.
 
Here is a link to the bug tracker...
https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1390

Comment: Ah, will do.  Sorry, not all that familiar with the process here.

Comment: Thank you for repling. When you post it as an answer. Please put the answer to "Your Answer". When you click "Post Your Answer", it is posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here turns out to be a bug in gspread 6.0.0.

Downgrading to gspread 5.12.4 resolves the issue, and the bug fix is slated for release in gspread 6.0.1.

Bug tracker is here:
github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1390